# which is faster :active pseudo or add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a large amount of `<li>` tags on a page but I need to change the background image of each one individually. So in my css i'd either have

```
.className {
    background: red;
}
.className:active {
    background: lime;
}
```

If I was to do an onClick event, i'd do very similar

```
.className {
    background: red;
}
li .active_class1 {
    background: lime;
}
```

What's faster, to set a class active and add the style or add a class to add the style? Because in both cases I need to change the background colour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding an extra class is an extra step you do not need if you can use native pseudo selectors. So, the latter (using pseudo) is faster. Only adding the class on each li will make it slower.